How to bring cooked salmon to camping, to be consumed the following day?
I want to bake salmon and transport to camping to be eaten the following day. Any suggestions on how to keep it cool?

What sort of camping? Driving a car directly to a campsite vs. hiking 10 miles at high elevation are gonna need very different methods of packing. Either way, though, I'd start with freezing the cooked fish.

related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/86228/how-to-keep-a-lunch-box-fresh-for-more-than-2-hours. I'm not sure there will be other answers than in the linked question, but let's see what comes up.

also see: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18237/67

I don't think you want to freeze for consumption the next day, as you risk textural degradation with freeze-thaw, but that could help reduce risk. You  need to keep it cold.  Chill the salmon as quickly as possible after cooking. You are going to have to keep it below 40 degrees F (4.5 C) until shortly before it is reheated or consumed.  A quality cooler and ice (and/or freezer packs) is the best option.

I would not freeze the cooked fish. I would suggest to explore new ways of cooking the Salmoon.
Most of the people are obsessed with sanitize but I would recommend:

Small fridge with ice will mantain as a normal Fridge, get two ice bags one on the bottom and the other on the top. And It will longer much than 3-4hours.
It is an option cooking on vacuum bags. You can cook your vegetables a little and roast the Salmon, then throw all to the Vacuum Bag and with a vacuum sealer do the vacuum. But you must find a bag that resist 100 or 120 Celsious to boiled or to put it on the owen. I have never tryed this, but it obvisuly last a lot althought the preparation it is a bit longer.
Cooked the salmon, and do the vacuum on a jar. Thats also an option but you the appearance might not be the best, the important thing it is the flavour.
You can marinade/picke/souse (I do not know how it is called in English) your salmon, and to the vacuum on a jar. But it is a strong flavour (the marinade, I do not know if you want this) and the appereance also might not be the best => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eitv8V9MQW8 (You must use jar. If you use enought vinager you could not use to vacuum the jar)
You could use a salty technique, like this => https://www.melaniecooks.com/russian-salted-salmon-recipe-how-to-make-salt-cured-salmon/5847/

Sorry if my english it is not greate

Hi, thank you for taking your time to write an answer. Sadly, I think it misses the point. The question is about baked salmon. You list different ways to preserve the salmon, but none of them results in something that tastes the same as baked salmon. More importantly, some of your suggestioons won't actually preserve the salmon! Some pickling recipes might also preserve it, but certainly not all. And the vacuum bag suggestion is very misleading, because the salmon will be unsafe to eat without refrigeration.
